# running a shell script once build passes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a job that is running unit tests on a project build and then ssh into a staging server and pulling down from the master branch. Right now I'm using the post-build-script but this is running regardless of pass/fail. I'm trying to use the parameterized build plugin to trigger a new job when the build is passed. So far I've created the new job and set to trigger in the configuration of the original.

The new job is building ok on its own but the original job isn't triggering it. From 'Add post-build action' I've selected 'Trigger parameterized build on other projects' with build triggers:
Projects to build: new_job, Trigger when build is: Stable or unstable but not failed.

Any ideas appreciated!

C

Comment: The build log should have some indication of why the second job isn't being triggered; could you post the last few lines ?

Comment: [parameterized-trigger] Downstream builds will not be triggered as no parameter is set.

Comment: Do you actually need to pass a parameter to the second build ?  If not, check "Trigger build without parameters".

Comment: Ok that got it working. I thought that that option would go back to triggering the second job regardless of pass/fail. Is that not the case? Gareth if you want to change your comment to to an answer I can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't actually need to pass a parameter to the second build, make sure that "Trigger build without parameters" is checked in the parameterized build trigger options.

Answer (score 2):

The "Post build task" allows you to query the console log of the build step, and is executed only when criteria is met.

Jenkins writes `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` in the console log for every build step that had passed.
In your "Post build task" step, under **Log text** just put `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`, and under **Script** put your linux script/commands.

This way your script/commands will only be executed if the **Build Step** was successful